# Chamar método PUT de uma App xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

Preciso fazer um update de minha ***App***. Estou tendo algumas dúvidas para passar os devidos parâmetros para a ***URL*** do serviço e executar o ***PUT***. O serviço está funcionando, testando pelo Postman, consigo realizar o Update, então só falta pela ***App***. A minha dificuldade está na passagem da ***Do evento do botão*** para o método e no método o ***objeto*** que vou montar. Eis o evento do botão **click**

```
private async void Aprovar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string motivo = ent.Text;
      await dataService.UpdateProdutoAsync(??????, motivo);
}
```

O motivo está correto. O outro parâmetro é o IdOrcamento. Eu tenho ele em algum lugar, talvez na var ***_data***, mas a questão toda está na minha ***dataService***, conforme abaixo

```
public async Task UpdateProdutoAsync(int id, string value)
        {
            string url = $"http://meu_site/autorizador/api/itens/{id}/{value}";
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url, id));
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(??????);
            var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            response = await client.PutAsync(uri, content);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro ao atualizar produto");
            }
        }
```

No ***JasonConvertObject*** é que reside a dúvida. Montar o objeto, se to passando tipos primitivos apenas. Devo passar o objeto ***Liberacao***, pois no servico ele representa uma entidade do BD, mas eu não tenho ele neste contexto, tenho-o antes dessa tela, que ele é passado por um ***GET***.

**EDIT1**

Tentei algumas soluções, mas continua dando erro: Eis as soluções tentadas. Na tela de chamada do Serviço, eu tenho apenas ***itens***. Bem, então passei pelo construtor dessa classe o objeto ***Liberacao***. E nesse momento então, passo como parâmetro para o método. Ele vem preenchido corretamente, mas está dando um erro sem tratamento, e o erro não diz nada. Vejam o código como ficou.

```
private async void btnItens_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPageItens(_idorcamento, libera));
        }
```

O código, tenho ***libera*** que é o objeto que eu passo pelo construtor da classe de **Itens**

```
private async void Aprovar(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string motivo = ent.Text;
            List<ItensLib> lib = new List<ItensLib>();
            lib = _data;

            var lista = liber
                .Where(l => l.IdOrcamento == IdOrcamento)
                .ToList();

            await dataService.UpdateProdutoAsync(IdOrcamento, motivo, lista);
        }
```

O código acima, é o clique do botão, onde eu pego a ***Liberacao*** correta e passo para o método.

```
public async Task UpdateProdutoAsync(int id, string value, List<Liberacao> liber)
        {
            string url = $"http://www.inetglobal.com.br/autorizador/api/itens/{id}/{value}";
            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url, id));
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(liber);
            var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            response = await client.PutAsync(uri, content);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception("Erro ao atualizar produto");
            }
        }
```

Veja nesse sreenshot que há informação e está correta
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E essa é ***Service***, que está dando erro. Esse é o Screenshot do erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT2**

Coloquei um try..catch e peguei essa mensagem:

> at Autorizador.Service.DataService+d__4.MoveNext
>   () [0x00152] in
>   C:\Mobile\Autorizador\Autorizador\Autorizador\Service\DataService.cs:62

O que pode dar esse erro?

**EDIT3**

Tenho quase a certeza que o problema está na var ***data***. Ela recebe um objeto do tipo ***Liberacao*** e esse objeto dentro do meu App, não exatamente igual ao objeto dentro do serviço. Isso no ***GET*** funciona, mas o ***Get*** já vem formatado da serviço e ao receber no App, já é feito o **CAST** para os tipos que o ***App*** vai usar. Porém, no ***PUT*** é diferente, o caminho é inverso, eu passo do **APP** para o serviço e acho que isso está fazendo esse erro.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente quero dizer que o problema é todo meu. Fiquei tão mergulhado no centro do problema que não olhei para a periferia dele. Isso fez com que não conseguisse analisar cada linha e tentar dar uma solução, mas depois de uma baita oração, não há problema que Deus não corrija. A minha ***URL*** estava errada. Copiei e colei, acrescentei os parâmetros, mas esqueci de chamar o Serviço correto, que seria o de Update e não o de Itens. Claro, isso ninguém, a não ser eu poderia corrigir. Corrigi e já consigo atualizar. Agora, é trabalhar nas cores, eventos de botão e levar para o cliente ver, orar e vender. Podem me xingar, só não a minha mãe que já se foi, rs.

```
string url = $"http://meu_site/autorizador/api/itens/{id}/{value}"; //errada

string url = $"http://meu_site/autorizador/api/atualiza/{id}/{value}"; //correta
```